# How do I get a valid NodeHandle in a rqt plugin

Tags: ros, nodehandle, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need a NodeHandle in order to make my library work properly. I am also using this library in a rqt plugin. Should I just create a new Nodehandle (don't think that this is a good idea) or is there any API which gives me a valid NodeHandle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65802/how-do-i-get-a-valid-nodehandle-in-a-rqt-plugin/) by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like I can just instantiate a new NodeHandle. According to the  [documentation](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a0eae6a7fd8c216c3f0860aec44ca81ba) there is no problem with that:

> When a NodeHandle is constructed, it checks to see if the global node state has already been started. If so, it increments a global reference count. If not, it starts the node with ros::start() and sets the reference count to 1.

But still are there any better options and do I need to be aware of anything?

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) with karma: 71 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no special need for handling nodes in your `rqt` plugins. Implementation of `node` in ROS is well modularized so that you can operate nodes either via `NodeHandle` (C++) or via `rospy`.

Also, inspired by your question, I added some practices you may want to consider on making `rqt` plugins [here](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin#Practices_to_follow_on_making_rqt_plugins).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) on 2013-06-25**:
So you would also suggest just to construct a NodeHandle (in C++)?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-06-30**:
I'm not sure what you mean by "construct a NodeHandle". I would instantiate `NodeHandle` as a variable and use it.